# How to use a facebook intent on android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

In order to share a post on facebook ( also gmail , sms...)  I have used

```
public class ShareActivity extends Activity {

    // the button + the editText
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
    EditText text= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);          

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                // type of intent 
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text.getText().toString());
                ShareActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share :  "));
            }
        });
    }      
}
```

but when I start my activity it is stopped unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

place this line `text= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);` call.

Comment: your `EditText text` is null as you init before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);` call.

Comment: Yes that works thank you ,I just moved EditText text and set it as final ,and installed the facebook.apk application on my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The final code :

public class ShareActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);     

 // the button + the editText
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
    final EditText text= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);


    button.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    // type of intent 
                        intent.setType("text/plain");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text.getText().toString());
                        ShareActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share :  "));
                }
                }
        );

}
```

}